# Creating a zoom-invariant grid overlay for an image

Tags: html, css

Here is a 3x3 grid overlaid on an image using an absolutely-positioned table.  The grid does not exactly fit over the image at zoom levels other than 100%, presumably due to rounding error when converting raw pixel values to zoomed pixel values.  How can this be fixed?

http://jsfiddle.net/LYX6T/

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
    <img width="201" height="144" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Color_icon_green.svg/200px-Color_icon_green.svg.png" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.imageWrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.overlay table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    height: 46px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/LYX6T/2/

Please tell me if I missed some of the requirements. I've set the table width to the width of the image, but left alone the width and height of the `<td>`. The image of the grid you provided was a demo right? Some of the problems come with the the anti alias and not equal sized columns of the image.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.imageWrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 201px;
    height: 144px;
}
.overlay table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Actually, `table-layout: fixed` and `border-collapse: collapse` are not even necessary - the only change needed is to put the width on the whole table.  I wonder why this didn't work when I tried it on my real-life example...  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. Thanks for the informative feedback. Good luck